# How To Add Random Number Query String Within PHP Array Links

Tags: php, arrays, string, url, random

The objective is to add a random number to the end of rotating images in a PHP array to prevent browsers from caching the image. The number should be appended to the end of the image URL I have the array, and it works great. I have a random number generator, and that works. I'm doing something wrong when using PHP to apply a random number to the links in the array.

Here is the array sample which contains link and image:

```
<?php
$content1 = '<a href="http://example.net" title="Example 1" target="_blank"><img src="http://example.com/gallery/image-1.png" alt="Image 1" width="300" height="250" class="gallery-image"></a>';
$content2 = '<a href="http://example.net" title="Example 2" target="_blank"><img src="http://example.com/gallery/image-2.png" alt="Image 2" width="300" height="250" class="gallery-image"></a>';
$content3 = '<a href="http://example.net" title="Example 3" target="_blank"><img src="http://example.com/gallery/image-3.png" alt="Image 3" width="300" height="250" class="gallery-image"></a>';
$content4 = '<a href="http://example.net" title="Example 4" target="_blank"><img src="http://example.com/gallery/image-3.png" alt="Image 4" width="300" height="250" class="gallery-image"></a>';
$content = array($content1, $content2, $content3, $content4,);
shuffle($content);
?>
<?php print $content[0] ?>
```

This is the random number generator:

```
<?php echo rand() . "\n"; ?>
```

What I want should look like this:

```
$content1 = '<a href="http://example.net" title="Example 1" target="_blank"><img src="http://example.com/gallery/image-1.png?29384756" alt="Image 1" width="300" height="250" class="gallery-image"></a>';
```

I've attempted to put the random number generator in the array's text string, but I'm doing something wrong, as either it won't generate a number, or the PHP code displays within the HTML, so I'm unsure of how the random number would generate within the array HTML text.

Again, the objective is to add a random number query string to the end of the image URL so the array still displays the image and prevents a browser from caching the image when/if a page is refreshed.

Any ideas? Any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
$rand = rand();
// ...
$content2 = '<a href="http://example.net" title="Example 2" target="_blank"><img src="http://example.com/gallery/image-2.png?' . $rand .'" alt="Image 2" width="300" height="250" class="gallery-image"></a>';
// ...
$content = array($content1, $content2, $content3, $content4,);
shuffle($content);
```